# Removed Eigen CMake config file

Tags: eigen, ubuntu-trusty, ubuntu, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I'm having an issue with compilation after moving to an indigo platform on ubuntu 14.04. As I understand it, from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Migration), [here](https://github.com/ros/cmake_modules/blob/0.3-devel/README.md#usage), [here](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/adv_user_guide/catkin_migration_indigo.html), and [here](https://github.com/ros/catkin/issues/492) the FindEigen.cmake is now in /opt/indigo/share/cmake_modules/cmake/Modules/. I see this on my system, and I followed the instructions to add cmake_modules as a dependency in both the package.xml and  CMakeLists.txt, however, I still get the same error.

The exact error message i get is:

```
    CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:75 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "eigen" with any of
  the following names:

    eigenConfig.cmake
    eigen-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "eigen" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "eigen_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "eigen"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  vigir_atlas_ros_control/vigir_atlas_controller/CMakeLists.txt:20 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pachu/flor_repo/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/pachu/flor_repo/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

So... I'm not really sure what else to try. I was working with vigir_atlas_ros_control/vigir_atlas_controller/CMakeLists.txt to add the dependencies but nothing seemed to change. Do i have to change something in /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193233/removed-eigen-cmake-config-file/) by [pachuc](https://answers.ros.org/users/20216/pachuc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-09-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

cmake variables are case sensitive, are you sure you're using `find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)`?

Here is a pull that includes the sum total of the changes you'd (ideally) need to make for migration:

https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/pull/45/files

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2015-05-03**:
In case it's unclear to anyone else, this wasn't a case sensitivity issue. The CMakeLists.txt was missing `find_package(cmake_modules REQUIRED)`.

**Comment by [qiyuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/22630/qiyuan/) on 2015-06-02**:
Hi ! I have add "cmake_modules" in find_package . But it still have the same error showed above. Is it something i miss?